# Can't add ListBox item from another form

Tags: c#, wpf, forms, listbox

The problem: I've got 2 forms. In one is a ListBox and in the other Form a button. I want a ListBox item to be added when I trigger the button in the second form. Tried it with the following code, the calculation works, but for some reason it doesnt add the item to the ListBox.

Form with the ListBox:

```
    public void addList(string sName)
    {
        listBox.Items.Add(sName + " " + Annuitätenrechner.zgErg.ToString("0.00") + "€" + " " + Annuitätenrechner.zmErg.ToString("0.00") + "€");
    }
```

Form with the button:

```
    public void bAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string sMonate = monate2.Text;
        string sZins = zins2.Text;
        string sName = name2.Text;

        if ((monate2.Text == "" && zins2.Text == "") || (sMonate.Contains('-')) || (sZins.Contains('-')))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Die eingegebenen Werte müssen größer als 0 sein.");
        }

        else
        {
            Daten data = new Daten();
            data.AnBetrag = int.Parse(betrag2.Text);
            data.AnMonate = int.Parse(monate2.Text);
            data.AnZins = double.Parse(zins2.Text) / 100;

            GlobaleDaten.AlleAnnuitaeten.Add(data);

            Annuitätenrechner annuitätenrechner = new Annuitätenrechner();
            annuitätenrechner.AnRechner(data);

            MainWindow mainwindow = new MainWindow();
            mainwindow.addList(sName);
        }
    }
```

Feel free to ask if you need more information.

Comment: `MainWindow mainwindow = new MainWindow();` creates a new instance of your MainWindow class. You certainly want to call the method on the existing instance instead. You can get it e.g. by `var mainWindow = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;`. However, consider creating a view model class that is shared by both windows.

Comment: best approach is delegate.

Comment: @Clemens worked perfectly, thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Send a reference of FormWithListBox to FormWithButton, sample:

```
public class FormWithListBox
{
    private void openFormWithButton()
    {
        var formWithButton = new FormWithButton(this);
        formWithButton.Show();
    }

    public void addList(string sName)
    {
        listBox.Items.Add(...);
    }
}

public class FormWithButton
{
    private readonly FormWithListBox _form;
    public FormWithButton(FormWithListBox form)
    {
        _form = form;
    }

    public void bAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _form.addList("...BlaBlaBla...");
    }
}
```